# Is there a simple method to separate streets from rooftops?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I'm working on extracting rooftops from satellite images. I have a problem with separating the inner streets from the rooftops in the image. After working with AI only (no neural networks), the result always includes both the streets and the buildings and I can't find a way to separate them.

This is the original image

[image]

and this is the image after the AI detection

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried it with Dilating and Opening your result image with this result (yours would look even better with raw data)

[**Result Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpb0e.jpg)

I think this is "the simple method" to solve it, otherwise you should use more accurate AI approach. 
Here is code. You can display images during process to understand every step.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

THRESHOLD = 10
DILATE_SIZE = 16
OPEN_SIZE = 47

img = cv2.imread("roofs.jpg", -1)
#using red channel - roofs ar
red_channel = img[:, :, 2]

# kernels
kernel_dil = np.ones([DILATE_SIZE,DILATE_SIZE])
kernel_er = np.ones([OPEN_SIZE,OPEN_SIZE])
# threshold
(t, img_bin) = cv2.threshold(red_channel, THRESHOLD, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
img_bin = cv2.morphologyEx(img_bin,cv2.MORPH_DILATE,kernel_dil)
img_bin = cv2.morphologyEx(img_bin,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel_er)
# to show result only
img_res = img
img_res[:,:,1] = img_bin[:,:]
cv2.imshow("img",img_res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite("res.jpg",img_res)
```

Comment: Thank you, I used your code to make a mask and intersected it with my previous results and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

What about postprocessing result image with classic morphology filters?
Dilation and Erosion with a bigger kernel afterwards would work really well here.

Comment: I tired that but it didn't work well. it didn't separate them, just shrank the area of the connected component of both the streets and the buildings.